# Fancybox multiple pop ups close form on submit?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, fancybox-2

I got two popus set up to open one by one, after 1st one is closed, by timer, i want the second one to be closed by the submit button,
This is the website : http://merlinmoon.com/
 My Code
!st pop up is a youtube Iframe
HTML:
for the Second Pop up

```
<div id="mews">

<div class="cd-form-wrapper cd-container panelssss">

<form class="cd-form" method="post" action="Believe-Masters.zip" onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(true);">


    <input type="name" id="cd-email" class="cd-email" name="cd-email" placeholder="NAME">
    <input type="email" id="cd-email" class="cd-email" name="cd-email" placeholder="EMAIL">
    <input type="submit" class="cd-submit" value="">

</form>


</div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#custom-stuff-blea .various').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.fancybox.close();
    }, 192000)
}, 1000);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'true',

    'afterClose': function() { 
        $("#custom-stuff-blea .various2").fancybox().trigger("click");
    }
});
});
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".various3").fancybox({
                    maxWidth    : 800,
                    maxHeight   : 600,
                    fitToView   : false,
                    width       : '70%',
                    height      : '70%',
                    autoSize    : false,
                    closeClick  : false,
                    openEffect  : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',

                });
            });
        </script>
```

I want to notice that onsubmit is not working :(, can you help me ? i will appreciate any help.
Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do a jquery `click()` on the submit button and then run:  `$.fancybox.close();` am i missing something here?